# How to change URL of my application from localhost to server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost, hosting

Please guide me how to change URL of my application from localhost to server.

For example for the page Active.aspx local path that I'm getting is here.

```
http://localhost:1532/Active.aspx
```

and I want to get this is:

```
http://domain.com/Active.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the site to still be on your machine:

- Open notepad as Administrator
- Open C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
- add a line '127.0.0.1    domain.com'   without the ''
- save file, close notepad
- open iis
- create a site and give it the hostheader domain.com
- point the site root at your files

BINGO!

(Let me know if you get stuck and I'll update answer)
(If you mean how to you put it live and available to everyone, read more of the internet!!)